# print all the titles of a content type by php

Tags: 7

I created a content type: "period".

Then, I created instances of this content type.

Now I would like, on a page tpl.php put the instructions, to print all the titles of the instances that I put on this content type. is it possible?

Comment: To print list of items you can use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module.

Comment: I would have an array with instances of the content type ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the "best" way (most future-proof etc.) would be to use an [`EntityFieldQuery`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7):

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'period');

$results = $query->execute();
if (!empty($results['node'])) {
  $nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($results['node']));
  foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    // Do something with $node->title
  }
}
```

There are other options but they either involve deprecated methods or going directly into the node/revision tables, which can be a pain.

If you need this list in page.tpl.php make sure you don't put the code directly in the template file (it's bad practice and can cause problems with caching). The best place would be in a preprocess hook in your theme's template.php file, or a module file.

Comment: hello, thanks for your explanation. I plan not long in Drupal and PHP code I put in the template. How should I do? You have something for me to read? thanks ...

Comment: I think [Setting up variables for use in a template](http://drupal.org/node/223430) would probably be the best place to start